# Determining the reliability of weather forecast

Tags: dataset, forecasting

> How well do weather forecasts predict the future weather?

For example, I would like to know how likely it is to be raining when forecasts predict 70% raining risk 3 days ahead of time.

I know there are plenty of weather data sets, but are there any data sets which contain information about *forecasts* specifically?

Has anything like this been done before?

Answer (score 9):

There's certainly a huge literature on the accuracy of weather forecasts, including some work that led to [widely used general techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score) for evaluating predictions.

[A data set of historical forecasts from a particular model is available from NOAA](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/forecasts/reforecast2/index.html).  The project sounds very cool, but the data looks quite complex.  This is not the forecast from your local TV station!

Comment: this answer was using in 2017 on the OpenData site [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11698/1511)

Answer (score 0):

I too was after the same type of data a couple of years ago, and amazingly enough I was unable to find the forecasts themselves once the particular date has passed. It means that you'd want to collect the forecasts actively over a period of time. While you're at it, I'd also suggest collecting a few types of forecast horizons: one day ahead, two days ahead, and until 10 days ahead (some websites offer that far ahead weather forecasts).